# Better way than this.oView.oParent.oParent.oParent.oParent.setModel(foo, bar)?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to set a jsonModel to my SAPUI5 component from one of my component controllers. Within the component, I am using an app or splitapp.

I want to avoid getting elements by their ID. What is the best way to get the closest "__ComponentX" object in the hierarchy from somewhere within the component, so that is works regardless of how many levels of 'oParent' I am deep, so that I can use the same function in each component?

Should I ask the object to return an oParent, as long as it doesn't return null, or is there a faster way that takes less time during runtime?

Please let me clarify: I do not want my subcomponent to change my parent component, but I am talking about the DOM tree hierarchy within my component. My DOM tree is as follows from top to bottom (by sId): `__component0, __jsview0, __app0, __app0-Master, __jsview1.` I want a function to access `__component0`, whether I am calling it from `__jsview0, __app0` or `__jsview1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem, regardless of how deep in your component you are.

I made a function in which it is possible to add a sapui5 jsview, and the function finds the owner (when you operate from inside a component, it returns the component) based on owner id.

```
function sourceComponent(oAny) {
  return sap.ui.getCore().getComponent(oAny._sOwnerId);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Every component should play around in their own sandbox. So, a sub component should not be responsible to reach and set a model of its parent. If components are tightly coupled or really necessary then such communication should be handled by eventing. e.g.

```
// Fire ModelNeeded event on the control tree to inform responsible component
this.fireEvent("ModelNeeded", { modelName : "whatever" }, false, true);
```

and componentX should listen it.

```
this.attachEvent("ModelNeeded", function(oEvent) {
     var sModelName = oEvent.getParameter("modelName");
     var oModel = createModel();
     this.setModel(oModel, sModelName);
     oEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Please let me clarify: I do not want my subcomponent to change my parent component, but I am talking about the DOM tree hierarchy within my component. My DOM tree is as follows from top to bottom (by sId): `__component0`, `__jsview0`, `__app0`, `__app0-Master`, `__jsview1`. I want a function to access `__component0`, whether I am calling it from `__jsview0`, `__app0` or `__jsview1`.